# Async/Await is not working as expected with for loop statement

Tags: javascript, node.js, es6-promise

I am new to Javascript and nodejs. While trying to understand how promises and callbacks work, i tried calling a function in a 'for' loop as shown below. What i was trying to achieve is to print 'i' value every 2 seconds using promises. However, the program waits for 2 seconds and prints i value 3 times and exits.

```
for(let i = 0; i < 3 ; i++){
    func(callback,i);
}

async function func(callback,i){
   await callback(i);
}
function callback(i){
    return new Promise((res,rej) =>{
        setTimeout(()=>{
            console.log('i = ',i)
            res();
        }, 2000);

    })
}
```

Can anybody please help me understand why this is happening?

Comment: Your `func` is pretty needless. You could just call `callback(i)` directly, with the same result.

Comment: It’s because `async` keyword transform `func` returns to `Promise`, and you should use `await` when `func` calls (if you want to wait while this `Promise` will be resolved).

Comment: ALL async functions return a promise.  If you want the `for` loop to pause, you have to `await` the promise that `func()` returns.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are pretty close. The missing information is `async` functions (your `func()`) implicitly returns an `AsyncFunction` object which implicitly returns a Promise itself too ([doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function)).

Your code using [immediately invoked function expression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immediately_invoked_function_expression) would be

```
(async () => {
    for(let i = 0; i < 3 ; i++){
        await func(callback,i);
    }
})()

async function func(callback,i){
   await callback(i);
}
function callback(i){
    return new Promise((res,rej) =>{
        setTimeout(()=>{
            console.log('i = ',i)
            res();
        }, 2000);
    })
}
```

Please note now in most of the browsers is natively available the construct `for await..of` ([doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for-await...of)). You can try experimenting this one too.

Answer (score 3):

You can just wrap your loop with `async` immediately executed function and add `await` within it (as was already suggested here):

```js
(async () => {
  for(let i = 0; i < 3 ; i++){
    await callback(i);
  }
})();

function callback(i){
  return new Promise((res,rej) =>{
    setTimeout(()=>{
      console.log('i = ',i)
      res();
    }, 2000);
  })
}
```

Here is my original answer before Bergi's edit:

```
(async () => {
  for(let i = 0; i < 3 ; i++){
    await func(callback,i);
  }
})()

async function func(callback,i){
  await callback(i);
}

function callback(i){
  return new Promise((res,rej) =>{
    setTimeout(()=>{
      console.log('i = ',i)
      res();
    }, 2000);
  })
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Here are some functions which help you understand how promises work with Arrays, where we make common mistakes.

```js
function promiseFunction(v) {
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
        setTimeout(() => resolve(v), 1000);
    });
}
function f1() {
    [1, 2, 3, 4]. forEach(async(i) => {
        const v = await promiseFunction(i);
        console.log(`-f1 v- ${v}<br/>`);
    });
    console.log('all done<br/>');
}
async function f2() {
    await Promise.all([1, 2, 3, 4].map(async(i) => {
        const v = await promiseFunction(i);
        console.log(`-f2 v- ${v}<br/>`);
    }));
    console.log('all done<br/>');
}
async function f3() {
    await [1, 2, 3, 4].reduce((p, i) => {
        return p.then(async () => {
            const v = await promiseFunction(i);
            console.log(`-f3 v- ${v}<br/>`);
        });
    }, Promise.resolve());
    console.log('all done<br/>');
}

async function func() {
   console.log('f1');
   await f1();
   console.log('f2');
   await f2();
   console.log('f3');
   await f3();
}

func();
```

f1() will print `all done` first and then print 1,2,3,4 at once after a second.
f2() will print 1,2,3,4 at once after a second then print `all done`.
f3() will print 1,2,3,4 in every second, and then print `all done`.

Comment: Needs to be in an async function context though....which is not what is showing in OP code. Try running it yourself

Answer (score -1):

You need to wait for async function to complete

```js
for(let i = 0; i < 3 ; i++){
    await func(callback,i);
}
```

But since you can't use `await` keyword in the global scope, you will need to wrap your `for` loop in an async function, and than call it

```js
async function myTest(){
    for(let i = 0; i < 3 ; i++){
        await func(callback,i);
    }
}
myTest()
```

Answer (score -2):

You async function func also returns a promise so you need the await keyword before its call.

```
for(let i = 0; i < 3 ; i++){
    await func(callback,i);
}
```